# find returns weird file order on RHEL but not on OSX

Tags: rhel, find, osx

When I enter

```
find . -iname "[0-9]*.nii"
```

on my OSX machine it returns:

```
./03_Rest_fcMRI/9793_01_03_1.nii
./04_VEMP/9793_01_04_1.nii
./04_VEMP/9793_01_04_2.nii
./05_Tapping/9793_01_05_1.nii
./05_Tapping/9793_01_05_2.nii
./06_Adaptation/9793_01_06_1.nii
./06_Adaptation/9793_01_06_2.nii
./06_Adaptation/9793_01_06_3.nii
./06_Adaptation/9793_01_06_4.nii
./07_SWM/9793_01_07_1.nii
./07_SWM/9793_01_07_2.nii
./07_SWM/9793_01_07_3.nii
./08_Foot_Tapping/9793_01_08_1.nii
```

When I enter the same line of code on RHEL, I get:

```
./06_Adaptation/9793_01_06_3.nii
./06_Adaptation/9793_01_06_4.nii
./06_Adaptation/9793_01_06_2.nii
./06_Adaptation/9793_01_06_1.nii
./03_Rest_fcMRI/9793_01_03_1.nii
./08_Foot_Tapping/9793_01_08_1.nii
./04_VEMP/9793_01_04_2.nii
./04_VEMP/9793_01_04_1.nii
./07_SWM/9793_01_07_3.nii
./07_SWM/9793_01_07_2.nii
./07_SWM/9793_01_07_1.nii
./05_Tapping/9793_01_05_2.nii
./05_Tapping/9793_01_05_1.nii
```

The file order on OSX seems logical to me. The one on RHEL does not. I know I can get the same order on RHEL by piping to sort, but this is not my issue.

I am trying to understand why find on RHEL outputs this non-alphanumeric order.

Comment: I tried it, but it still gave me the same output.

Comment: Don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find does not sort the files, it lists them out in the order it finds them. It also traverses directories in the order it finds them. You cannot make any assumptions about the order but I believe it will be repeatable in the sense that if you run find again, you'll get the same order.

On Linux, files are *not* stored in alphabetical order. Maybe they are on OSX, or maybe they happen to have been created in alphabetical order.

The non-sorting is not laziness or a bug, it's meant to be that way. If it were to sort the files, it would not be able to output anything until it had finished traversing the file system, which could take minutes in many cases.

Comment: As a sidenote, the OS X version of `find` may be run with `-s` option to "traverse the file hierarchies in lexicographical order"